# Product of a First Countable Space by a Fréchet Space

Tags: general-topology

It's easy to see that the product of two First Countable spaces is First Countable, and it's easy to show that every First Countable space is a Fréchet Space (i.e, if $A \subset X$ and $p \in \bar A$ then there exists a sequence $s_n$ of elements of $A$ such that $s_n \rightarrow p$).

On [Alan Dow's "More set-theory for topologists"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016686419500034E) I saw that there is an nice example of two Fréchet spaces such that their product is not Fréchet. But I was wondering, what if one of them is also First Countable? Will the product be a Fréchet Space?

PS: I don't know if I was supposed to post this question here or in MO. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y=\{p\}\cup(\omega\times\omega)$, where $p\notin\omega\times\omega$, points of $\omega\times\omega$ are isolated in $Y$, and the $$B_n=\{p\}\cup\big([n,\omega)\times\omega\big)$$ for $n\in\omega$ are a local base at $p$. $Y$ is metrizable: it’s homeomorphic to $$\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}\cup\{\langle 2^{-m},2^{-n}\rangle:m,n\in\Bbb N\text{ and }n\ge m\}$$ as a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$.

Let $X=\{q\}\cup(\omega\times\omega)$, where again points of $\omega\times\omega$ are isolated, and the sets $$B_f=\{q\}\cup\{\langle m,n\rangle\in\omega\times\omega:n\ge f(m)\}$$ for $f\in{^\omega\omega}$ are a local base at $q$. It’s not hard to check that $X$ is Fréchet. If $q\in\operatorname{cl}_XA$ for some $A\subseteq\omega\times\omega$, there must be some $n\in\omega$ such that $A\cap\big(\{n\}\times\omega\big)$ is infinite; if

$$A\cap\big(\{n\}\times\omega\big)=\{\langle n,m_k\rangle:k\in\omega\}\;,$$

where $m_k<m_{k+1}$ for each $k\in\omega$, then $\big\langle\langle n,m_k\rangle:k\in\omega\big\rangle$ converges to $q$ in $X$.

Now let

$$\Delta=\left\{\big\langle\langle m,n\rangle,\langle m,n\rangle\big\rangle:m,n\in\omega\right\}\;.$$

Any open nbhd of $\langle q,p\rangle$ contains a set of the form $B_f\times B_n$ for some $f\in{^\omega\omega}$ and $n\in\omega$, and

$$\big\langle\langle n,f(n)\rangle,\langle n,f(n)\rangle\big\rangle\in\Delta\cap(B_f\times B_n)\;,$$

so $\langle q,p\rangle\in\operatorname{cl}_{X\times Y}\Delta$. However, $\Delta$ is sequentially closed in $X\times Y$, so $X\times Y$ isn’t even sequential.

Comment: You took the time to type up this huge answer, but you spelled neighborhood as "nbhd." Is it for economy, or are you worried about offending speakers of some version of English with your spelling?

Comment: @Matt: Habit, ease of typing, and a certain amount of laziness. *Neighbo(u)rhood* is a pain to type, and *nbhd* is nearly self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am writing some notes on general topology and I would like to add an reference for this example. Do you know one?

Comment: @Vinicius: I don’t know the original reference, but the example is given (without proof) in section **d-3, Fréchet and Sequential Spaces**, of K.P. Hart, Jun-iti Nagata, & J.E. Vaughan, [*Encyclopedia of General Topology*](http://www.amazon.com/Encyclopedia-General-Topology-K-P-Hart/dp/0444503552).

Comment: Why is there $n$ such that $A \cap(\{n\} \times \omega)$ is infinite?

Comment: @Vinicius: Ack! I had a horrible typo in that paragraph: both places where I had $Y$, I meant $X$. It’s fixed now. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Well, now I can't see why X is fréchet

Comment: @Vinicius: I proved the only hard part starting with ‘If $q\in\operatorname{cl}_XA$’; what part is giving you trouble?

Comment: I can't see why there exists such $n$.

Comment: @Vinicius: If not, then for each $n\in\omega$ there is an $f(n)\in\omega$ such that if $\langle n,m\rangle\in A$, then $m<f(n)$. But then $B_f$ is a nbhd of $q$ disjoint from $A$.